# Какие последствия вызова функции с ошибкой no return statement in function returning non-void?

Tags: c++

Есть такой код:

```
void func1()                                                                                                                                                                                                       
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
     std::cout << "func1" << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                                         
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                               
void func2()                                                                                                                                                                                                       
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    std::cout << "func2" << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                                         
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                               
bool func3()                                                                                                                                                                                                       
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    std::cout << "func3" << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                                         
    func1();                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    func2();                                                                                                                                                                                                   
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                               
int main(int argc, char* argv[])                                                                                                                                                                                   
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
      func3();                                                                                                                                                                                                   
      return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                  
}
```

как можно видеть в функции `bool func3()` ошибка: функция не возвращает значение. Если скомпилировать эту программу:

```
 g++ -O2 main.cpp
```

то получим следующее поведение

```
func3
func1
func2
func3
func1
func2
Ошибка сегментирования (стек памяти сброшен на диск)
```

Вопрос: что произошло? почему функция `func3` вызвалась два раза? и почему произошла ошибка сегментирования, насколько я понимаю такая ошибка возникает только при неправильном обращении с памятью.

В ассемблере это выглядит так(я убрал вывод в поток для краткости, поведение сохраняется):

```
    .file   "main.cpp"
    .text
    .p2align 4
    .globl  _Z5func1v
    .type   _Z5func1v, @function
_Z5func1v:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    endbr64
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   _Z5func1v, .-_Z5func1v
    .p2align 4
    .globl  _Z5func2v
    .type   _Z5func2v, @function
_Z5func2v:
.LFB5:
    .cfi_startproc
    endbr64
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE5:
    .size   _Z5func2v, .-_Z5func2v
    .section    .text.unlikely,"ax",@progbits
    .globl  _Z5func3v
    .type   _Z5func3v, @function
 _Z5func3:
 .LFB2:
    .cfi_startproc
    endbr64
    .cfi_endproc
 .LFE2:
    .size   _Z5func3v, .-_Z5func3v
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
  main:
  .LFB3:
    .cfi_startproc
    endbr64
    .cfi_endproc
  .LFE3:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
    .section    .note.gnu.property,"a"
    .align 8
    .long    1f - 0f
    .long    4f - 1f
    .long    5
  0:
    .string  "GNU"
  1:
    .align 8
    .long    0xc0000002
    .long    3f - 2f
  2:
    .long    0x3
  3:
    .align 8
  4:
```

Интересно что если скомпилировать без оптимизации то программ отработает корректно.

```
g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0
```

Comment: Undefined behavior — он такой — может произойти что угодно. Но почему произошло именно то, что произошло — действительно интересно...

Comment: покажите функции `func3`, `main` в ассемблере `main.s` после `g++ -O2 -S main.cpp`

Comment: Добавил `main.s` в вопрос

Comment: слишком укоротили, не вижу вызовы `call func..`. Короче, `endbr64` - это NOP-ы на intel. И нет команды `ret`. Скорее всего из-за этой новой команды `endbr64` у вас возможен цикл.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Посмотрел ассемблерный код. Там нет команды `ret`. И функция продолжает выполнять функцию `main`. В **godbolt** зацикливания не произошло.

```
func3():
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edx, 5
        mov     esi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC2
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::cout
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:std::cout
        call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)
        call    func1()
        call    func2()
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        call    func3()
```

https://godbolt.org/z/ojnWP8

Comment: а там все очень сильно зависит от компилятора. Сам сидел игрался этим и оно очень интересно